# ArcGIS API for Python not plotting Spatially Enabled Dataframe

Tags: pandas, arcgis-python-api

I'm using Python 3.6.8, Pandas 0.25.3, and ArcGIS API for Python 1.6.2. I'm pulling data from an API and viewing it in a pandas dataframe using a Jupyter Notebook. The data has several attributes including latitude and longitude. I can successfully convert the Pandas dataframe to a spatially enabled dataframe, call the `.head()` method and see the new SHAPE column. I can create a map object but when I try to plot my dataframe on the map object, the map does not update and display the points. I've included my code below:

```
# Define parameters for API call
headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Api-Token': 'Key',
    'Agency-ID': 'ID'
}

# Call API and save to a varialbe
response = requests.get('URL', headers=headers).json()

# Convert json to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(response)

# Convert dataframe to spatially enabled dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_xy(df, x_column = 'longitude', y_column = 'latitude')

# Create map object and display map
gis = GIS()
m = GIS().map()
m.center = [36.081179, -79.556955]
m.zoom = 9
m

# Plot dataframe
df.spatial.plot(map_widget= m)
```

Line 22 returns a map and Line 25 returns 'True' but no updates to the map are made. I've also tried using the renderer and `symbol_type` and `symbol_style` attributes.

```
df.spatial.plot(map_widget=m,
        symbol_type='simple',
        symbol_style='d', # d - for diamonds
        colors='Reds_r',
        cstep=10,
        outline_color='Blues',
        marker_size=10)
```

This block of code replaced Line 25 in the first section but did not display in the map either.

I've been through the documentation and the guide on [GitHub](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-python-api/tree/master/guide) but cannot find anything to make it work.

Comment: A couple of things to check: 1. Is SHAPE properly ending up as a column of Geometry objects? 2. Would your data be visible at that center and zoom if you were the one plotting it manually?